# Error trailing semicolon in smart contract on solidity?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am  trying to write a smart contract and line 1 is bringing up an error : ParserError: Found version pragma, but failed to parse it. Please ensure there is a trailing semicolon. --> contracts/Mycontract.sol:1:1: | 1 | pragma solidity ^.0.8.1; |

I already have a semi colon in the contract what am I missing here? I am attemping this on the browser in Remix.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format for first line for importing pragma shall be like

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

The correct format is `^0.8.1` (no dot after the caret `^`).

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;
```

It should be like the given form above.